# must match URL address returning a lot of documents - Elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I'm simply trying to check how many documents have the same `link` value. There is something weird going on.

---

Let's say one or more documents has this `link` value: `https://twitter.com/someUser/status/1288024417990144000`

I search for it using this JSON query:

```
/theIndex/_doc/_search

{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "link": "https://twitter.com/someUser/status/1288024417990144000"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

It returns documents 522 of 546, with the first document being the correct one. It acts more like a `query_string` than a `must match`

If I search another more unique field like `sha256sum`:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "sha256sum": "dad06b7a0a68a0eb879eaea6e4024ac7f97e38e6ac2b191afa7c363948270303"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

It returns 1 document like it should.

I've tried searching `must term` aswell, but it returns 0 documents.

---

## Mapping

```
{
  "images": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "sha256sum": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "link": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "number_of_shards": "1",
        "provided_name": "images",
        "creation_date": "1593711063075",
        "analysis": {
          "filter": {
            "synonym": {
              "ignore_case": "true",
              "type": "synonym",
              "synonyms_path": "synonyms.txt"
            }
          },
          "analyzer": {
            "synonym": {
              "filter": [
                "synonym"
              ],
              "tokenizer": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "a5zMwAYCQuW6U4R8POiaDw",
        "version": {
          "created": "7050199"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I wouldn't think such a simple issue would be so hard to fix. Am I just missing something right in front of my eyes?

Does anyone know what might be going on here?

Comment: What is the mapping of your `link` field? it is now contained in your mapping

Comment: @Val This was my bad. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I don't see the `link` field in your mapping (is it `source`?), I suspect it is a `text` field and text fields are analyzed. If you want to perform an exact match, you need to match on the `link.keyword` field and it's going to behave like you expect:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "link.keyword": "https://twitter.com/someUser/status/1288024417990144000"
                                 ^
                                 |
                              add this
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh ok, I see. I was missing the .keyword. Thank you so much!